# Legitimate cases of having .equals() behaving inconsistently with .compareTo()?

Tags: java, c#, object-oriented, python, comparison

Java documentation says it's "*strongly recommended*" to have them behaving consistently.

But are there legitimate cases of java/c#/python/etc `Object.equals()` method behaving inconsistently with the method `Comparable.compareTo()`?

Comment: You wish your coworkers to strangle you to death?
I can think of no good scenario.

Comment: lol. i've just been told that BigDecimal has this peculiarity (which kinda makes sense)

Comment: Why does it make sense for `BigDecimal`?

Comment: you can't guarantee that two decimal numbers having different precision are equal. i said "kinda" tho. mathematically it doesn't make sense

Comment: @kdgregory BigDecimal makes a distinction between `1.00` and `1.0000` as different. So while they sort to the same location (compareTo), they have a different internal state and are not *equal*. You could also think of a rational class where `1/3` and `2/6` have the same value but different *state*. The confusing part would be that *equal* in doesn't imply mathematical equality but rather object equality (which is where it gets confusing when dealing with mathlike objects).

Comment: Thank you very much, @MichaelT. It's nice to see that an experienced programmer can answer that question. I wrote the comment, however, in the hope of getting the OP to think about the differences.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason you have *two different methods* is that they do *two different things.*

The `.equals` method returns a boolean value indicating whether the object on which you call the method *is equal to* the object passed in as a parameter  (for some definition of "is equal to" that is consistent with the nature of the object being compared).

The `.compareTo` method returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.  That makes it a useful method for sorting; it allows you to compare one instance with another for purposes of *ordering.*

When the Java documentation says that these two methods must behave consistently, what they mean is that the `.equals` method must return `true` in exactly the same situations where the `.compareTo` method returns zero, and must return `false` in exactly the same situations where the `.compareTo` method returns a nonzero number.

Is there any good reason to violate these rules?  Generally no, for the same reasons that

```
#define TRUE FALSE
```

is a really bad idea.  The only legitimate reason for inconsistent behavior is hinted at in the Java documentation itself: *"[if the] class has a natural ordering that is inconsistent with equals."*

To drive home the point, you can actually define `.equals()` in terms of `compareTo()`, thus guaranteeing consistent behavior.  Consider this `.equals()` method from a [Rational class](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/12oop/Rational.java.html) which, after a few sanity checks, simply defines `.equals` as `compareTo() == 0`:

```
public boolean equals(Object y) {
    if (y == null) return false;
    if (y.getClass() != this.getClass()) return false;
    Rational b = (Rational) y;
    return compareTo(b) == 0;
}
```

Comment: I've also seen it the other way round, where `CompareTo()`'s zero stars is defined in terms of equals, but this makes much more sense now that I've seen it done this way.

Answer (score 7):

This confusion would occur in situations where there are conflicting understandings of `equals`.

`compareTo` is 'easy' in that it asks a simple question 'which one is bigger?' If you were given a bunch of *Things*, how do you sort them?

`equals` on the other hand wants to ask 'are these the same thing?'

BigDecimal in Java is one such place where there are conflicting understandings of what it means to have two things being equal.

```
BigDecimal foo = new BigDecimal("1.00");
BigDecimal bar = new BigDecimal("1.000");
```

These two entires will have the same meaning for sorting.  They, however, are *not* the same when it comes to equality. They have a different underlying state (the precision of the number) and that means they are not *equal* but `foo.compareTo(bar)` will return 0.

Consider this, if you had a `Map qux = HashMap<BigDecimal, Object>()` for some reason, do you want `qux.put(foo,foo)` to take the same spot as `qux.put(bar,bar)` and thus evict the earlier insertion?

So, while they are math equals (which is how compareTo sorts them), they are not inner state equals, and thus the necessity of the inconsistency here.

Yes, this inconsistency comes at the price of a higher cognitive load for dealing with BigDecimal.  It means maps may not behave like you want them to... and the question is "which map do you want to behave 'right'?"

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        BigDecimal foo = new BigDecimal("1.00");
        BigDecimal bar = new BigDecimal("1.000");

        HashMap<BigDecimal, String> hash = new HashMap();
        TreeMap<BigDecimal, String> tree = new TreeMap();

        hash.put(foo, "foo");
        hash.put(bar, "bar");

        tree.put(foo, "foo");
        tree.put(bar, "bar");

        System.out.println("hash foo: " + hash.get(foo));
        System.out.println("hash bar: " + hash.get(bar));

        System.out.println("tree foo: " + tree.get(foo));
        System.out.println("tree bar: " + tree.get(bar));
    }
}
```

<sup>[ideone](http://ideone.com/OvdoUV)</sup>

Output:

```
hash foo: foo
hash bar: bar
tree foo: bar
tree bar: bar
```

Because `compareTo` returned 0, in the TreeMap, `bar` evicted `foo` when bar was inserted.  However, because these are different objects with different internal state and thus different hash codes, they were both able to exist within a HashMap.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

> Note: care should be exercised if `BigDecimal` objects are used as keys in a SortedMap or elements in a SortedSet since `BigDecimal`'s *natural ordering* is *inconsistent with equals*. See Comparable, SortedMap or SortedSet for more information.

And so, thats the problem, the inconsistency and the "there's no good answer to this" dilemma.

---

One could also imagine this with a Rational class where one wants to keep `2/4` having the internal state of `2/4` so that:

```
Rational twoFourths = new Rational(2,4);
Rational oneHalf = new Rational(1,2);

System.out.println(twoFourths); // prints 2/4
System.out.println(oneHalf);    // prints 1/2
System.out.println(twoFourths.compareTo(oneHalf)); // prints 0
System.out.println(twoFourths.equals(oneHalf));    // ???
```

And you are once again up against that same question.  Are these equal with the mathematical sense of equality (which means the hashCode needs to also return the same value?) or are they not equal using the object oriented state of the object sense of equality despite being the 'same'.

Answer (score 2):

The "legitimate reason" for having `equals()` inconsistent with `compareTo()` is if they serve different real-world purposes.

Let's start with `BigDecimal`. If you're simply sorting a list of values, you probably don't care about scale. However, if you're checking for equality, what you're really checking is that *the series of operations that led to this result are the same*. To be honest, I'm surprised that the developers of `BigDecimal` did not choose to include rounding mode in their test for equality.

As another example, consider customer address entities stored in a database. You get cheaper postal rates if you sort addresses for mass mailings, so you might choose to base the natural ordering on the postal code and street address. However, even if two addresses are identical in all outward respects, they may not be *equal*, because a particular address belongs to a particular customer (and you'll get into all sorts of issues if you try to share them).

Those are two cases where equality requires a stronger guarantee than ordering. The reverse is possible although unlikely: I once implemented a system where I needed to ensure stable ordering of different instances, so added an additional test in comparison, such that different instances would never compare as 0. But I can't remember the details of that system, and can't come up with a good example on the spur of the moment.

As other people have said, you have to be careful when you use objects where equality and order are inconsistent. Personally, I prefer to implement a `Comparator` rather than have the classes be `Comparable`.

Answer (score 2):

> But are there legitimate cases of java/c#/python/etc Object.equals() method behaving inconsistently with the method Comparable.compareTo()?

Yes, for example, here is a legitimate case in Python 2.x. The `float` value for NaN does not compare equal (`==`) to itself, yet `cmp()` (equivalent to `compareTo`) will return `0` (equal), which is inconsistent with the result of `==`:

```
>>> x = float('nan')
>>> x == x
False
>>> cmp(x, x)
0
```

(Note: `cmp()` was removed in Python 3; that's why I specified Python 2.x only.)

NaN is kind of a special case in most languages, because IEEE 754 defines NaN as not equal to itself, something which is not true for basically any other value encountered in programming.

Interestingly, Java and C# do not have this inconsistency. Even though NaN in the primitive type `double` is not equal to itself using the primitive equality operator, the `equals` method of `Double` objects will test NaN equal to itself, to preserve consistency with `compareTo` and to allow use as keys in dictionaries. So they opted to make primitive equality and `equals` inconsistent, rather than make `equals` and `compareTo` inconssitent.

Ruby also does not have this inconsistency. NaN compared to itself with the `<=>` operator returns `nil` (incomparable). So they avoided the inconsistency by restricting comparability to a subset of numbers.